# Why is the GridDB Cluster not failing over to a new master node

Tags: griddb

I am running a GridDB Cluster environment and there was a a network failure in one of our data center early in the morning today. I noticed the Cluster environment is did not switch to a new master node automatically even though all the nodes in the environment are online.

Anyone has similar experience and how did you resolve that.

I confirmed that all the nodes in the cluster were online.
I check event log to see if there was any Warning or Error message.